# Building Parsec dedup workload with parsecmgmt fails

Tags: linux, gcc, benchmarking, parsec

I am trying to build Parsec_3.0 dedup workload on skylake server with  gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0. I managed to build streamcluster and canneal successfully without issues, however with dedup I get the error, when using same command: parsecmgmt -a build -p dedup

ERROR:

```
installing man1/smime.1    
smime.pod around line 272: Expected text after =item, not a number    
same with lines: 276, 280, 285, 289    
POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 70.    
make: *** [install_docs] Error 255    
Makefile:680: recipe for target 'install_docs' failed

[PARSEC] Error: env PATH=/usr/bin:/home/akhorguani/parsec/parsec-3.0/bin:/usr/lo
cal/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/b
in:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/grid5000/code/bin:/home/akhorguani/parsec/parsec-3.0/bin
 /usr/bin/make install failed.
```

In `/usr/bin/pod2man` line 70 is `" print "  $files[1]\n" if $verbose; "`.  But it's predefined file from the host machine so I don't think it would contain errors, most likely I might need to change something in parsec files.

So maybe anyone had faced the same problem and can help to fix it?

Comment: *`POD document had syntax errors`* - POD files are often used to create man pages. The POD file gets run through Perl's `pod2man`. Maybe you can skip the documentation. For example, OpenSSL uses POD files,  and they provide a `make install_sw` to avoid building and installing the docs.

Comment: You mean Solaris FreeWare (sfw)? I found it in configuration file but I don't think it's installed in server, so should I provide it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jww mentioned, the error is due to some syntax errors on POD files from the SSL library that parsec uses. I had the same error and managed to build by replacing all instances of `=item` followed by a number with `=item C<Number>` in the POD files.

The files you need to modify are on the following folders:

```
$ folder-where-you-installed-parsec/pkgs/libs/ssl/src/doc/apps

$ folder-where-you-installed-parsec/pkgs/libs/ssl/src/doc/ssl
```

You can see the changes you need to do in this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/edujtm/80117adbd3e4a15faf9ef2108900732b).

I did the changes by hand but you can probably make a script that reads the files and fixes it for you.

I believe that the issue is platform specific because my colleague built it without any problems with Manjaro linux, while I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Eduardo's answer worked for me!

It seems the gist is out of date as ome of pod files have changed in the newer PARSEC version.

```
sed -i.bak 's/item \([0-9]\+\)/item C<\1>/g' *
```

The script above carries out needed transformation. Run it from `apps` and `ssl` folders